# how to put include(phpfile) to variable?

Tags: php, variables, include, themes

I want like theme or template untouched like default then other php can use it as their theme. but i have problem that i cant put theme to variable with generated before output print.

example here:

main code:

```
$word[0] = "test";
$word[1] = "hello word";
$word[2] = "example";
$word[3] = "wordwordword";
$word[4] = "variable";

while(5)
{
$name = "TEST".$word[$i];
output .= include("theme.php");

$i++;
}
echo "OUTPUT:";
echo "TITLE";
echo $output;
```

theme.php code:

```
hello <?php echo $name; ?>
```

**NOTE:** i know while loop will break but this is just example code. because i use while(mysql_fetch_array($result)). thanks

Comment: `while(5)`? Will this ever end (i.e., is there a `break` in `theme.php`)?

Comment: no this is just example... only focus problem is put include to variable...

Comment: Ok, then you should really [consult the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) regarding `include()` and how it handles return values, specifically examples #4 and #5.

Comment: next time use answer for your answer than comment..anyway, thanks jensgram.

Comment: I don't consider a link to the manual an answer *per se* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code can't possible work, so I reckon it's pseudo code. Anyway, the issue is fixed with use of the ob_* functions in PHP, as follows. This is how the majority of template parsers in php work:

```
<?php
$word = array( );
$word[0] = "test";
$word[1] = "hello word";
$word[2] = "example";
$word[3] = "wordwordword";
$word[4] = "variable";

$i = 0;
for( $i = 0, $j = count( $word ); $i < $j; $i ++ ) {
    $name = "TEST" . $word[$i];

    ob_start( );
    include( 'theme.php' );
    $output .= ob_get_clean( );
}

echo $output;
/**
 * Result:
 * 
 * TESTtest
 * TESThello world
 * TESTexample
 * TESTwordwordword
 * TESTvariable
 */
```

Comment: it works..Thanks, Berry. i didn't know about ob_*.. and i havent try experience with ob_*.. hehehe i will try start learn about ob_*.. Thanks.