# Specifying a php include to use a certain stylesheet?

Tags: php, stylesheet

I am dividing my website in the typical php include way. If I want the includes to use their own stylesheet how is this done? For example if I have include "header.php", how can I make it so that a stylesheet only applies to this include?

Comment: Try use similar my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621796/how-to-put-includephpfile-to-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this either by including a different stylesheet to begin with, or by giving your `<body>` element an `id` or `class` attribute that enables you to write selectors such as

```
body#header {
    /* ... */
}
```

The first approach plugs in at the `<head>` tag render code, the second does so at the `<body>` tag render code. You need to write your code such that one of these places also knows which PHP script you intend to include (or have already included).

Answer (score 1):

you cannot bind css to a php-include. you respond to a browser with HTML-code. with php you may control which css(-file) will be included in the HTML finally. you may bind css to certain tags, or classes, or ids. but those are HTML-concepts and have no relation to PHP except for the fact that PHP will control the final HTML-code.

Comment: Okay thank you, I was hoping there was some way of doing this for simplicity but oh well.